# How do I upgrade PHP progressively over several websites on a single server?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, ubuntu-12.04

I have a set of PHP-based websites hosted on a single Linux server that I need to upgrade PHP for. However, as some of the sites are QA / staging and others are production, I need to do this progressively.

That is, I would like the QA sites to go first so I can check that upgrading PHP does not break anything, before rolling out to production. What's the best way to go about this?

The sites are all served through Apache and have their own vhost file.

I'm imagining that I can (somehow) install a new version of PHP at a specific point and through configuration (Apache? vhost?), specify that a site uses this version of PHP (rather than the one at `/usr/bin/php`).

The PHP versions in question are fairly old: I'm upgrading from PHP 5.3 to 5.4 at this point. Although (obviously) I need to get to 5.6 pretty soon. So I'm after a process that I can re-use.

Comment: This would be pretty hard - and would probably cause more issues then it would resolve if its even doable.   A better solution might be to move the QA sites into a VM running the newer version of PHP first and see how it works.     The alternative would be to run 2 versions of the web server on different ports (or IP addresses making sure the server only binds to the appropriate ones), but this is going to be complex and prone to break things.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a set of PHP-based websites hosted on a single Linux server
>   that I need to upgrade PHP for. However, as some of the sites are QA /
>   staging and others are production, I need to do this progressively.
>   That is, I would like the QA sites to go first so I can check that
>   upgrading PHP does not break anything, before rolling out to
>   production. What's the best way to go about this?

If you have your QA/staging and production servers mixed into one server this degree, you’re doing it wrong. You *won’t* be able to launch a different version of PHP per virtual host; it’s simply one version of PHP per Apache install per server.

That said, my approach to a setup like this—since I like using Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS) myself—would be to create a desktop virtual machine environment using VirtualBox or similar software. Make sure that virtualized setup matches your current production server setup as much as possible and get that up and running. Then once you have that “sandbox” running correctly on your desktop, then attempt to upgrade PHP.

This might seem daunting if you just built up the server over time, but honestly software developed for LAMP stacks can work anywhere as long as the codebase, data storage and configuration are setup correctly. I do local PHP development on Mac OS X (for example) and regularly deploy to an Ubuntu server without much worries or thought put to the issue.

But then you say this:

> The PHP versions in question are fairly old: I’m upgrading from PHP
>   5.3 to 5.4 at this point. Although (obviously) I need to get to 5.6 pretty soon. So I’m after a process that I can re-use.

I think you might be overly concerned about a non-issue unless you are 100% positive that the coding for the websites you have would actually benefit from a PHP
version upgrade.

I have dozens of Ubuntu 12.04 servers deployed specifically for LAMP needs like yours and nobody is sweating the PHP 5.3 issue since it is technically “old” but PHP 5.3 is considered one of the more stable PHP versions out there. Also, Ubuntu 12.04 is an [LTS (Long Term Service) release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) that is [supported until April 2017](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases); 2 years away.

Which means technically while version numbers for the software in Ubuntu 12.04 will superficially seem to be “out of date” as far as security patches goes, the LTS designation means that critical security patches and such will be [backported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backporting) to PHP 5.3 and similar packages.

This kind of long term support is the exact reason why system administrators choose LTS installs: No need to worry about upgrades until they are truly needed.